# Change url from profile.php?user=myUsername to profile/myUsername with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using xamp to host my webpage on my PC and I want to change this url from

```
http://localhost/loginsystem/profile.php?user=myUsername
```

to

```
http://localhost/loginsystem/profile/myUsername
```

I have tried the following and doesn't work and in return gives server error 500.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^/profile/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) /profile.php?user=$1 [NC, L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^/profile/(.*)?$ /profile.php?user=$1 [NC, L]
```

Any help would be great still pretty new. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Also make sure that your .htaccess file is in the loginsystem folder. Otherwise you will need to put this in your rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^loginsystem/profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace .htaccess code with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Now you can get user query with GET request.

Comment: For more information, You can check https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html